# Not able to pop up alert box on page load

Tags: 2010, alert, codebehind

I have created a code behind file for a site page. The .cs file looks as follows :

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace CustPage
{
    public class MyCustPage:Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('it worked')</scirpt>");
        }
    }
}
```

I have used the following page directives :

```
   <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%> 
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WikiEditPage" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" meta:progid="SharePoint.WebPartPage.Document"       %>

 <%@ Assembly Name="CustPage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=44ba9bb23d3f44ca" %>
 <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

The page is getting displayed but no alert box is shown.
I don't the mistake that I might have done.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo here, but the closing tag should read </script>

Comment: </scirpt> insted of </script> ? tried that?

Comment: I have rectified the mistake. But still no pop up is shown. Do  I have to add again the assembly in gac? @MdMazzotti

Comment: You are mixing things up! As per your page directives, the page is a WikiEditPage, so it doesn't inherit your MyCustPage. Moreover, the Assembly Name part where you import your CustPage, is once again wrong. You must include the fully qualified class name, namespace, version, culture, PKT

Comment: I have changed the inherits to the my class fully qualified name and the assembly name. Now it is showing CustPage.MyCustPage is not a safe type

Answer (score 0):

You can try to register script blocks as show below.

> Not tested on site pages, but you can try.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "yourFunction", "alert('Something');", true);
```

Answer (score -1):

My Understanding is that your page is loading but the alert pop-up is not coming after the page is loaded. If that is the case you can directly add the below code under the Page_load/On_page_Load.

```
alert('It worked');
```

Let me know if my understanding of the problem is wrong.

Comment: You understood it correctly